# jQuery slideDown not fluid

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am working on a jQuery menu for my friend. The menu is done, the only problem is that the slide down is not fluid and I can't find the problem here.

jQuery code:

```
$.fn.vmenu=function(settings)
{
    vMenu={
        init: function(elem) {
            $(elem).find('li').each(function(){
                var u=$(this).children('ul');
                if (u.length>0) {
                    $(this).addClass('has_child');
                }
                var a=$(this).children('a');
                if (a.hasClass('active')) {
                    $(this).addClass('active').parents('li').addClass('open');
                }
            });

            $(elem).find('ul').each(function(){
                var o=$(this).find('li.open');
                var a=$(this).find('a.active');
                if (o.length == 0 && a.length==0) {
                    $(this).css('display','none');
                }
            });

            $(elem).find('a').click(function(){
                return vMenu.click($(this));
            });
        },
        click: function(elem) {
            var l=$(elem).parent('li');
            var u=$(l).children('ul');

            if (u.length == 0) {
                return this.forward(elem);
            }

            if ($(l).hasClass('open')) {
                $(l).removeClass('open');
                $(l).find('ul').stop(true,true).slideUp(300);
                $(l).find('li').removeClass('open');
                if($(l).children('a').hasClass('open')) {
                    $(l).children('a').css({color:'#939393'});
                    $(l).children('a').removeClass('open');
                }
            } else {
                $(l).addClass('open');
                $(u).stop(true,true).slideDown(300);
                $(l).children('a').css({color:'#F37121'});
                $(l).children('a').addClass('open');
            }

            return false;
        },
        forward: function(elem) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    vMenu.init($(this));
}

$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#vmenu').vmenu();
});
```

CSS code:

```
/* ### partner box ### */
.partnerBox { padding-top: 52px; width: 253px; float: left; background: url('http://www.realbingo.nl/images/partner-top.png') left top no-repeat; }
.partnerBox .bottom { padding-bottom: 12px; float: left; background: url('http://www.realbingo.nl/images/paasbonus-bottom.png') left bottom no-repeat; }
.partnerBox .mid { padding: 0 20px 0 15px; width: 218px; float: left; background: url('http://www.realbingo.nl/images/paasbonus-mid.png') left top repeat-y; }
.partnerBox h3 { padding-left: 5px; margin-top: -36px; color: #fff; font-size: 20px; }
.partnerBox ul { padding: 0px 0 0 0; margin-bottom: -5px; overflow: hidden; width: 100%; }
.partnerBox li { padding-left: 5px; font-size: 13px; float: left; list-style: none; width: 208px; line-height: 39px; border-bottom: 0px; }
.partnerBox li a { padding-left: 9px; color: #939393; text-decoration: none; display: block; background: url('http://www.realbingo.nl/images/arrow1.png') left center no-repeat; }
.partnerBox li a:hover { color: #F37121 !important; }
#vmenu li { border-bottom: #ece3e3 solid 1px; }
#vmenu li > ul > li { border-bottom: 0px; height: 30px; line-height: 30px; margin-top: -8px;}
.text ul{ line-height: 18px; margin-bottom: 2px; }
```

HTML code:

```
<div class="partnerBox">
    <div class="bottom">
        <div class="mid">
            <h3>Linkpartners</h3>
            <ul id="vmenu">
                <li><a href="#">Bingo</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Roulette</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Poker</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="text"><a href="#">Tekst</a>
                    <ul>
                        Dit is een lap tekst die door en door gaat tot het einde.. en verder... :D:D:D:D:D:D:D:D
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>   
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any tips and/or ideas to make the code more efficient are very appreciated too.

Comment: What about any of the hundreds of existing menus out there?

Comment: Because I want to practice my jQuery.. it's my first real script and i'm starting to get familiar with it.. + I hate standard stuff, I like to make my own ;)

Comment: That CSS formatting is _horrible_ to read. Also, which browser are you testing in? Some bowsers' Javascript engines aren't so fluid.

Comment: It might be horrible, but that was what already was in place.. I just edited it. Tested in IE9, Opera, FireFox and Chrome.. well I guess it isn't the browser then ;)

Comment: More on the tips side than an actual answer: you are already creating jQuery objects with your var l and var u declarations. Then you are re-wrapping them when you don't need to. Just use the cached versions you've already made. Also, you can chain your functions in most cases (preceding functions almost always return a jQuery object). You are also using $(elem) three times in your init when you could just cache it: var $elem = $(elem);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're talking about the slideDown jumping when it gets to the bottom of the reveal it is likely to be caused by the bottom margin on the ".text ul" CSS. jQuery can't calculate the height including margins.

If you're talking about the slideDown content moving around during the animation, this is often related to the top padding of either the element you're sliding or the first child element.